# How to start a conda/miniconda environment straight from working directory, in Windows?

Tags: python, windows, directory, anaconda, conda

I installed Anaconda virtual environment in my Windows machine. By defaults, all of the virtual environments created are stored in,

**C:\Users\userName\Anaconda3\envs**

so whenever I start the environment from the Anaconda Navigator, it will start the environment from **C:\Users\userName>**, which will need me to CD to more directories.

I've tried to invoke PowerShell and then start command prompt from it, but it doesn't working.

So, I want to know if I can directly run the conda environment that are stored in **C:\Users\userName\Anaconda3\envs**, in my working directory. Let say the working environment is in another disks.

Comment: `conda activate <env name>` you can use this to work in any virtual environment

Comment: @prashantrana no it doesnt work. it says, 'conda' is not recognized ..... until the end of statement.

Comment: you need to add anaconda to your system environment path

Comment: @prashantrana how to verify it?